# Adding a row to one dataset based on other dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have two data sets. The aim is to add a row to df1 if a new code appears in the df2 and the df2$LABEL is set to PRIV. I tried simply with the if clause, but it didn't work for me. I think maybe there is a solution with dplyr library. Logics I used (maybe will be helpful):

```
df1$CODE != df2$CODE & df2$LABEL == "PRIV"
```

Dummy examples of datasets with dput (df1 first and df2 second):

```
structure(list(OUTLETID = c("11N", "12B", "17C",                            
"44O"), CODE = c(4623,                                                                             
4623, 4111, 4343), 
PRICE = c(1.45, 1.45, 5.45, 5.03), LABEL = c("PRIV", "PRIV", "NON PRIV", "NON PRIV")), 
row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

structure(list(CODE = c(4623, 4205, 4551), 
PRICE = c(1.45, 1.17, 5.99), LABEL = c("PRIV", "PRIV", "NON PRIV")), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So in this example, a new row with CODE=4205, PRICE=1.17 and LABEL="PRIV" should be added to df1. As in df2 there is no OUTLETID, should be just NA in that column. This code should work for the general case, bigger datasets, not just for this small example.

Comment: Can you show expected output for this example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have to deal with large data sets, please find below a solution with the `data.table` package:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

rbind(df1,df2[CODE %in% setdiff(df2$CODE, df1$CODE) & LABEL == "PRIV",], fill = TRUE)
#>    OUTLETID CODE PRICE    LABEL
#> 1:      11N 4623  1.45     PRIV
#> 2:      12B 4623  1.45     PRIV
#> 3:      17C 4111  5.45 NON PRIV
#> 4:      44O 4343  5.03 NON PRIV
#> 5:     <NA> 4205  1.17     PRIV
```

Not clear for me if you want to keep or remove the "NON PRIV" label from the `df1`. So if you want to simultaneously remove the rows with "NON PRIV" label from `df1` you can use the following line of code:

```r
rbind(df1[LABEL == "PRIV"],df2[CODE %in% setdiff(df2$CODE, df1$CODE) & LABEL == "PRIV",], fill = TRUE)
#>    OUTLETID CODE PRICE LABEL
#> 1:      11N 4623  1.45  PRIV
#> 2:      12B 4623  1.45  PRIV
#> 3:     <NA> 4205  1.17  PRIV
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: But there can be many such codes not only this one, here looks like it will work only for this set code. It should be considered all codes which are in df2, but not in df1 and the label should be PRIV. @lovalery

Comment: O.K. @Adolf Miszka. Please find my edited answer above. Let me know if it works fine now. Cheers